# Como testar meu site em uma internet lenta?

Tags: aplicação-web, desempenho

Ao concluir o desenvolvimento de um site ou sistema, sempre testamos o desempenho do mesmo com a nossa internet.

Diante disso, existe alguma forma de simular o desempenho do meu sistema uma internet lenta para realizar tais testes sem alterar nada em minha conexão de internet?

Comment: Todas as respostas são ótimas e profissionais, mas até onde eu sei o throttling dos navegadores não simula a latência real de uma rede lenta. Também não simula taxas altas de perda de pacotes. Quer testar o site com uma internet lenta de verdade, usa uma conexão 3G da Tim...

Comment: @Renan Já testei muito desta forma, e fico feliz de falar que não preciso mais dela hoje em dia xD... Agora, sobre o trolling, ele realmente não simula a perda de pacotes (ou se simula eu ainda não achei configurar), mas a latência é passível de configuração, assim como download e upload.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta é uma resposta complementar, o Firefox também possui tem algo semelhante ao Chrome, primeiro selecione o "modo responsivo" no Developer Tools:

[image: dev]

E depois abra o segundo combobox e escolha a opção desejada:

[image: simular]

Além destes, existe um applet (que uso a um bom tempo) chamado [Sloppy](http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/), com ele é possivel simular não só para navegadores mas para quase qualquer ferramenta do sistema operacional, apesar de no site ele pedir para rodar diretamente é possivel baixar o e roda-lo diretamente em sua máquina, segue o repositório para download https://github.com/d6y/sloppy, limitando um dominio especifico:

[image: limitando]

Comment: Muito bom, gostei muito do Sloppy

Answer (score 18):

Uma forma de fazer isso é utilizando o próprio Google Chrome.

Com ele você consegue configurar a velocidade que deseja para realizar tais testes.

Para utilizar, basta ir nas **ferramentas de desenvolvedor (F12)**, na aba **Network** e selecionar a opção de "[Throttling](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limita%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_largura_de_banda)".

A imagem abaixo ilustra melhor:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
<sub>(fonte: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/imgs/throttle-selection.png))</sub>

Lembrando também que você pode desabilitar o cache em **disable cache** para testar o acesso sem utilizar o cache.

Você pode ver o tutorial completo [feito pela própria Google](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) para entender melhor como funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando, existe a possibilidade de fazer esse teste utilizando o [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).

Não vou entrar em detalhes de como se utiliza o mesmo, somente como configura-lo para simular velocidades diferentes de internet.

Editando o arquivo `<jmeter_home>/bin/user.properties` e adicionando as propriedades:

```
httpclient.socket.http.cps=0
httpclient.socket.https.cps=0
```

Altera essas propriedades para um valor desejável, como os exemplos abaixo:

```
Mobile data GPRS : 171 kbit/s = 21888
Mobile data EDGE : 384 kbit/s = 49152
Mobile data HSPA : 14,4 Mbp/s = 1843200
Mobile data HSPA+ : 21 Mbp/s = 2688000
Mobile data DC-HSPA+ : 42 Mbps = 5376000
Mobile data LTE : 150 Mbp/s = 19200000
WIFI 802.11a/g : 54 Mbit/s = 6912000
WIFI 802.11n : 600 Mbit/s = 76800000
Ethernet LAN ; 10 Mbit/s = 1280000
Fast Ethernet : 100 Mbit/s = 12800000
Gigabit Ethernet : 1 Gbit/s = 128000000
10 Gigabit Ethernet : 10 Gbit/s = 1280000000
100 Gigabit Ethernet : 100 Gbit/s = 12800000000
WAN modems V.92 modems : 56 kbit/s = 7168
ADSL : 8 Mbit/s = 1024000
ADSL2 : 12 Mbit/s = 1536000
ADSL2+ : 24 Mbit/s = 3072000
```

Para outros valores informar de acordo com a fórmula:

```
cps = (target bandwidth in kbps * 1024) / 8
```

---

Mais detalhes na [documentação oficial](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks).